# How to "stream" data from MongoDB with pyMongo?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo

I use the module pyMongo, which allows me to fetch the data from a MongoDB collection. I display the data in a console. Everything works but now I want to display the data "in live", i.e when a new data is added to the collection, it's displaying on the console.

Do you know some development practices to obtain this result ?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What version of mongo are you running? Changestreams was added in v3.6. You can read [this introduction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams) in Javascript but it isn't all very different in python.